# Is there a numeric multivalued fieldType that allows null values in Solr?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

### Question

Is there a way to have a numeric field type in solr that allows for null values and is multivalued?

e.g. `"my_number_field": [1, 3, null, 4]`

### Background

I'm trying to index some data that is being flattened from XML into JSON, where one field is numeric (currently `pdoubles`) and can have empty values.

```json
    {
        ...,
        "sector_code": [
            "52010",
            "P13"
        ],
        "sector_vocabulary": [
            "",
            "99"
        ],
        "sector_percentage": [
            "",
            "100"
        ]
    }
```

`managed-schema`:

```xml
<field name="sector_percentage" type="pdoubles" multiValued="true" indexed="true" required="false" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="pdoubles" class="solr.DoublePointField" docValues="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

When I try to index this into Solr I get the following error:

`Error adding field 'sector_percentage'='[,100]' msg=empty String]`

It would not be appropriate to set the value to 0 as the absence of a value in the source data can mean different things based on the context.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use `NaN` for non-existent `pdoubles` value in Solr.

`"my_number_field": [1, 3, "NaN", 4]`

Example query response with the field indexed:

```json
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"id:zz1234",
      "indent":"true",
      "fl":"sector_percentage",
      "q.op":"OR",
      "_":"1635517103316"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"numFoundExact":true,"docs":[
      {
        "sector_percentage":[50.0,
          "NaN",
          100.0]}]
  }}
```